# Good approach for matching 1000 records lists of Game title strings?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, search-engine

I need to implement some sort of string / text matching.
I have two lists of video game titles (names) that I need to match.
Lists are acquired from DB among other data using EntityFramework6. One record contains two unicode string, separated title prefix and rest of the title.

Example of List A:

```
prefix    title
An     | Amazing race
An     | Amazing Race 2
       | Super Racer
The    | Death race: Revenge
       | reveng of Björn the Dead racer: game with really long title
...
```

The typos and inconsistencies are intentional to show the nature of the data.
List A is editable by user, including hand-typed new records so typos, stuck-together words etc. are a possibility.
As a start, I'm currently going thru list B one record at time, trying to match it to some record in A or get 'no match', with simple case-insensitive comparison. Obviously not a great solution.

List B can be something like:

```
       | AmazingRace
       | Amazing Race
An     | amazing race 2: Even More Amazing
       | AmazingRace3
       | Gatez of C'thu'thotz: You will die every minute or possibly more
...
```

Records there are non-unique and possibly One A : Many B.
I have a view on 100s up to about 1000 of records in each list.

I am thinking of creating my own simple word indexing system, since the data are displayed in DataGrid so I guess it will be needed later anyway, for faster filtering and searching. Though I have little experience with implementing indexing. (My experience ends at per char Trie)
Another option is use of existing robust system like Lucene.net, though from what I found: its aimed at full-text so I'm not sure if it will work well for my case and it might have problem with not-so-much natural language words which are common in gaming world or non-english titles ?
Plus there might be another, better option I don't see now.

Advice on how to best approach this would be greatly appreciated.
(Please pardon my not so great english)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great approach for comparing two datasets in a very efficient way. This technique is called **SimHash**. In summary, it creates a fingerprint (an integer value) for a text based on the substrings it contains. The good thing is that you can use these fingerprints to compare documents instead of the complete text, and it is much faster as it is an integer value.

Here you have some links to start with:

- [Simple Simhashing](http://moultano.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/simple-simhashing-3kbzhsxyg4467-6/)
- [SimHash or the way to compare quickly two datasets](http://www.titouangalopin.com/blog/articles/2014/05/simhash-or-the-way-to-compare-quickly-two-datasets)
- [SimHash implementation in C#](https://github.com/AllenDang/simhash)

PS. If you have any doubt or need more information I can update my answer.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Thanks. I wonder how it will work with my specific data. I'm trying to implement it now and will get back.